# Parsing Ajax object response to array after passing from an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the ff. code which passes the object response from AJAX via an `<a>` tag's `id`

```
"<td>" + "<a id='"+userData+"' class='edit' href=''>Edit</a>" + "</td>"
```

However, when I checked the value contained in userData when it was retrieve via `event.target.id`

```
$('.edit').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(ev.target.id); // this prints the output shown below
    show_add_user_modal();
});
```

I get the ff. output when I used `console.log(ev.target.id);`

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Below is the entire `ajax` code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'controller/get_all_users.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(userData){
        console.log(userData);
        var len = userData.length;
        $('#table_users_record').find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var userId = userData[i]['id'];
            var userName = userData[i]['username'];
            var lastName = userData[i]['lastname'];
            var firstName = userData[i]['firstname'];
            var middleInitial = userData[i]['middleinitial'];
            var roleName = userData[i]['roleName'];
            var isActive = userData[i]['isactive'];
            $('#table_users_record').append(
                "<tr><td>" + userId + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + roleName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + userName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + lastName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + firstName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + middleInitial + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + isActive + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + "<a id='"+userData+"' class='edit' href=''>Edit</a>" + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + "<a id='' href='#'>" + "Deactivate" + "</a>" + "</td>" +
                "</tr>"
            );
        }
        $('.edit').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            //do something with click
            //alert(ev.target.id);
            console.log(ev.target.id);
            show_add_user_modal();
        });
    }
});
```

What is the correct way to parse it when retrieved through `event`?

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: The issue is because `userData` is an array of objects. Without knowing what the correctly formatted link should look like it's hard to say what the correct code would be.

Comment: You're using the userData as the ID, by default it will use the "toString()" of the array because the ID needs to be a string.
If you change that to something like "<a id='"+userData[i]['id']+" it should work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan @JuanTechera Do you suggest I just use one of the User properties such as `id` ? I will need to fill the modal `div` with the user details when EDIT option is selected by user

Comment: Can you post what data is you getting in user data.

Comment: @SudhirOjha When I `console.log(userData);` I get `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` but when I access the properties of userData by index of codes contained within the `for()` loop like `var userName = userData[i]['username'];` , I am able to get the actual username